# How to make public facing ELB, private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb

Below is the elastic load balancer, taken from [here](https://github.com/shamhub/docker-jenkins/blob/master/stack.json#L102):

```
 "ElasticLoadBalancer": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "CrossZone": "false",
                "SecurityGroups": [ { "Ref": "ElbSecurityGroup" } ],
                "Listeners": [
                    {
                        "LoadBalancerPort": "80",
                        "InstancePort": "8080",
                        "Protocol": "http"
                    }

                ],
                "Instances": [ { "Ref": "EC2Instance"} ],
                "Subnets": [ { "Ref": "SubnetId"} ]
            }
        }
```

---

where ELB is behaving as public facing resource for Jenkins(running in EC2).

EC2 instance running Jenkins is also sitting in public subnet.

---

Currently ELB is public facing to Internet.

How to make ELB privately accessible within company network only?  Because ELB is generally used as public facing resource.

Comment: modify your security group to accept traffic from your companies external IP only.

Comment: @Jeremy I need to make sure that the source IP's are known before hand, that try reaching ELB. This approach looks like smelling approach, Isn't it?

Comment: Well, you either need to allow just the IPs you want, or set up a permanent site to site VPN with your AWS environment. Unless your organization is massive, it shouldnt be too hard to know where the traffic is coming from. You set it once, then don't ever have to touch it again as external IP address schemes don't change very frequently.

Comment: @Jeremy What about the approach on `scheme` property set to `internal`, as mentioned below? any comments

Comment: i interpret internal in the answer below to be internal to the AWS environment. in that case, your company resources will not be able to connect.

Answer (score 3):

There should be `scheme` property you should be able to set the value to `internal`

After that, you should be able to restrict access to the company subnets using security groups.

Reference:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-elb.html

> **Schema parameter** The type of load balancer. Valid only for load balancers in a VPC.
>
> If Scheme is internet-facing, the load balancer has a public DNS name
>   that resolves to a public IP address.
>
> If Scheme is internal, the load balancer has a public DNS name that
>   resolves to a private IP address.

Hope you find this answer helpful.

Comment: What does `scheme` set to `internal` signify?

Comment: did you get a chance to check the links i gave you, its clearly stated there. anyway updated my answer for you.

Comment: With this configuration, does the public IP  it get assigned to elb

Comment: it should not, why do you ask, is it happening

Comment: I will test it today

Comment: i am on it right now, I am creating a stack for work, will know it in few minutes

Comment: sorry this one i am not testing, i am testing your other question. can you test this one. but i am 99.99% sure it wont assign public ip, because whats the point of assigning public ip to internal

Comment: But the public DNS name should **not** be reachable from Internet. That is the whole purpose for making sure that ELB is accessible from within the company network. I don't understand, when documentation says: "If Scheme is internal, the load balancer has a public DNS name"

Comment: "If Scheme is internal, the load balancer has a public DNS name that resolves to a private IP address". That's fine. It will resolve to private ip address but it will not be reachable. Example case, If it resolves to let's say 10.1.1.1, how many people from the whole world using 10.1.1.1. who knows ? It's a private ip. Anyone can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If the company network is outside AWS cloud besides making the load balancer private by setting up the scheme property to "internal", you will need to set up a vpn between you company network and the AWS VPC + subnetwork where the jenkins EC2 instance is located.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-internal-load-balancers.html
https://aws.amazon.com/es/vpn/